# Angular Bootstrap Tabs , href doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use angular bootstrap tabs like that :

```
    <div >
    <tabset>
        <tab ng-repeat="t in tabs">
            <tab-heading>{{t.title}} <a  ng-click="removeTab($index)" href='#Evaluation'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></i></a></tab-heading>
            <!-- <div ng-bind='t.content'></div> -->
        </tab>
    </tabset>
</div>
<div id="Informations">Infos</div>
<div id="Evaluation">Evaluation</div>
```

and the js is :

```
monAppli.controller("Controleur", function ($scope) {
    $scope.tabs = [{        
        title: "Informations",
        content: '<h1>tab one</h1>'
    }, {
        title: "Evaluation",
        content: '<h1>tab two</h1>'
    }, {
        title: "Projets",
        content: '<h1>tab three</h1>'
    }, {
        title: "Notes",
        content: '<h1>tab 4</h1>'
    }
    ];
    $scope.removeTab = function (index) {
        $scope.tabs.splice(index, 1);
    }; 
});
```

but the href link doesn't work, it doesn't show each div separatly.. Somebody have any idea ? Thank you a lot
It's supposed to show thez div "Evaluation" when clicking on a tab, but it show nothing.

I've tried this also :

```
<div >
        <tabset>
            <tab ng-repeat="t in tabs">
                <tab-heading>{{t.title}} <a  ng-click="removeTab($index)" data-target="#{{t.title}}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></i></a></tab-heading>
                <!-- <div ng-bind='t.content'></div> -->
            </tab>
        </tabset>
    </div>
    <div id="Informations">Infos bla bla bla</div>
    <div id="Evaluation">try bla bla bla</div>
```

There is a fiddle there http://jsfiddle.net/alfrescian/ZE9cE/

But it doesn't show how to show one div related to one tab.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ted for your help, finnaly added ur code, and also took a look at https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ and it works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `href='#Evaluation'` to `data-target='#Evaluation'` (remove the href altogether).

Comment: Hello thank you a lot ! I've tried         <div >
   <tabset>
    <tab ng-repeat="t in tabs">
     <tab-heading>{{t.title}} <a  ng-click="removeTab($index)" data-target="#{{t.title}}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></i></a></tab-heading>
     <!-- <div ng-bind='t.content'></div> -->
    </tab>
   </tabset>
  </div>
  <div id="Informations">Infos</div>
  <div id="Evaluation">try</div> it still doesn't work, i dont know how to hide the 2 div "informations" and "evaluation"